# How to accessing specific matrix element or with specific index Haskell

Tags: haskell, matrix

I'm trying to access specific element of matrix. For instance to get every second element of sublist and give as single list back.

```
data Matrix a = M [[a]]
rowMatrix :: [[Int]] -> Int -> a
```

for ex  `rowMatrix [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]  3 ---> [3,7,11]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can, for each row, obtain the `k`-th element, so we can perform a mapping, like:

```
romMatrix :: [[a]] -> Int -> [a]
rowMatrix m k = map (!! k) m
```

Or for a `Matrix` type:

```
romMatrix :: Matrix a -> Int -> [a]
rowMatrix (M m) k = map (!! k) m
```

So here we create a list of elements where each element is the `k`-th element of the corresponding sublist.

Answer (score 1):

For each sublist, extract its `n`th element with the `!!` operator:

```
rowMatrix [] _ = []
rowMatrix (row:others) n = (row !! n) : (rowMatrix others n)
```

For example:

```
rowMatrix [[1,2,3], [2,3,4]] 2
[3,4]
```

You can also make this a bit crazier, but also more concise:

```
rowMatrix :: [[a]] -> Int -> [a]
rowMatrix listOfLists n = listOfLists >>= ((:[]) . (!! n))
```

Comment: somehow im getting compiler error, did you test it?

Comment: @mWelt: I think you confuse your `Matrix` data type and the signature of your function.

Comment: @mWelt, this is written for the underlying list type, and it shouldn't be hard to make this work for `Matrix`: some pattern matching should do the trick.

Comment: you both are right, i saw where i failed. thanks @WillemVanOnsem exactly was my confusing point

Answer (score 0):

Since rows are columns in the transposed matrix; to fit with your example; it is just

```
rowMatrix :: [[a]] -> Int -> [a]
rowMatrix xs m = transpose xs !! (m-1)
```

I had to fix your type, too. Also note the off-by-1 issue.

```
> rowMatrix [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]]  3
[3,7,11]
it :: [Int]
```

Comment: Actually it works with my type too, input does not have to be Int, could be any list of a. but your solution is also cool.

Comment: in that case, it should be `[[a]] -> Int -> [a]`.